# How to save jpeg image as Progressive JPEG?

Tags: php, image, jpeg, progressive

I have below function to save JPEG as Progressive JPEG. It saved, but not as progressive JPEG. Is this correct ?

```
function save($filename, $image_type = IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression = 75, $permissions = null) {

    if ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

        imageinterlace($this->image, true); //convert to progressive ?
        imagejpeg($this->image, $filename, $compression);

    } elseif ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF) {

        imagegif($this->image, $filename);

    } elseif ($image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG) {

        imagepng($this->image, $filename);
    }

    if ($permissions != null) {

        chmod($filename, $permissions);
    }
}
```

This is how i called save() function :

```
function img_reconstruct($saveto) {
  $image = new SimpleImage();

  $image->load($saveto);

  list($width, $height) = getimagesize($saveto);

  if ($width > 800 && $width < 1200) {

    $image->resize(800, $height);

    $image->save($saveto);

  }
 }
```

Comment: Hi Snoke, did you get this working? I am also looking for converting the jpeg to progressive jpeg.

Comment: Same here. Any idea why it might be not working, no matter if you use imageinterlace($this->image, true); or imageinterlace($this->image, 1);

Comment: Is jpeg format only gives the progressive images why not png format images? I have a doubt like I have seen all the blogs are talking about progressive jpegs only and not about any png format images. can someone clarify?

Answer (score 4):

try like below

```
imageinterlace($this->image, 1); //convert to progressive ?
```

may be issue with type casting